# Enemy attacks-Who gets hit?

Tags: gm-techniques

How do you guys decide which player gets hit when an enemy attacks? Do you just assign each character a die number and roll it?

Comment: Do you have a specific game in mind?

Comment: Welcome to the Role Playing games Stack Exchange site! We have a [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) that might be helpful in showing you what the site is about. Welcome again, and good luck.

Comment: for the record the question seems very clear to me.

Comment: @blade for my part, it's unclear or too broad without a system/family specified. Either OP's got one in mind but hasn't told us (unclear) or they want something that applies to [the thousands of RPGs out there](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/23970), many of which have differently-specified targeting rules, some of which don't have combat... (too broad). I've voted to leave it on hold until we know more.

Comment: @blade It may also be a duplicate; we already have this question asked for a few different game systems. We just need to know what game the question is about and then we can proceed correctly (assuming the asker hasn't disappeared on us).